# Class missing during startup but available afterwards

Tags: spring, tomcat, gradle, classpath

I'm migrating [a project](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/) from old Ant scripts to Gradle. For development, I'm using [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin), and the `java` and `war` plugins.

The project gets built in a Docker container, which works fine for me but not for my colleague. When he runs `gradle tomcatRun`, he gets an error like this:

```
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rsa]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rsa]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServletException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServletException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 20 more
A child container failed during start
```

I assume this is referring to `javax.servlet.ServletException`. However, if I force one of the servlets to throw a `ServletException` (which I can test because it loads fine on my machine), it can find that class with no problem.

My build file looks something like this ([full source here](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/97ab503ca198b3ca19c44b6419b5cf721a8a5295/src/spatialcubeservice/build.gradle)):

```
providedCompile (
    "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:$tomcatVersion",
)

compile (
    'com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:2.3.3',
    'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1',
    'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2',
    'commons-net:commons-net:3.4',
    'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA',
    'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.7.1',
    'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final',
    "org.springframework:org.springframework.web:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:org.springframework.web.servlet:$springVersion",
    'rome:rome:1.0',
)

runtime (
    'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2',
    "org.springframework:spring-oxm:$springVersion",
)

tomcat (
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:$tomcatVersion",
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:$tomcatVersion",
    "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:$tomcatVersion",
)
```

Is there another `ServletException` that I'm missing a .jar for? Or is it that the .jar might not have loaded during server startup, but gets loaded later? The app is currently [configured](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/6d66369ebf9895e91916b4e5da07aba49d28d95c/src/spatialcubeservice/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) to use servlet API 2.4. I've seen some other threads saying to upgrade it, but changing it to 2.5 didn't help.

- [build.gradle](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/97ab503ca198b3ca19c44b6419b5cf721a8a5295/src/spatialcubeservice/build.gradle)
- [web.xml](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/6d66369ebf9895e91916b4e5da07aba49d28d95c/src/spatialcubeservice/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)
- [Dockerfile](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/6d66369ebf9895e91916b4e5da07aba49d28d95c/Dockerfile)

Comment: It should be referring to the full class name (with packages) in the error message. Could your code be referring to a custom `ServletException` in the default package (probably by accident)?

Comment: I thought so too. Our code doesn't refer to `ServletException` without qualification (according to `git grep`), but maybe one of the libraries does. Spring has a [`NestedServletException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/NestedServletException.html), but judging by the docs it extends `javax.servlet.ServletException`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Thilo - implementing my own `ServletException` in the default package let me see what the error should have been: another error that hinted strongly at a misconfigured classpath!

Answer (score 0):

OK this is embarrassing: there must have been some stale files hiding in my colleague's source tree, maybe masked by `.gitignore`. Doing a clean checkout of the repository has "fixed" the problem.

I say "fixed" because we never really got to the bottom of it: the error was *saying* that it couldn't find `ServletException`. I implemented my own `ServletException` in the default package (thanks Thilo for the tip), but it just showed another similar error. Anyway it works now, so chances are it was just a classpath problem involving a file that shouldn't have been in the source tree.